# AWS IoT Javascript SDK can not create client

Tags: javascript, aws-iot

I'm using Vue.js, TypeScript, and the `aws-iot-device-sdk` package and like to subscribe to a IoT topic. This is how I create a new client:

```js
import AwsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk';
import { config } from 'aws-sdk';

client = new AwsIot.device({
    region: 'foo',
    host: 'foo',
    clientId: 'foo',
    protocol: 'wss',
    accessKeyId: config.credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretKey: config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: config.credentials.sessionToken
});
```

One seconds later I get this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
    at nReadingNextTick (_stream_readable.js)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at onwriteDrain (_stream_writable.js)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_readableState' of undefined
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reading' of undefined
    at maybeReadMore_ (_stream_readable.js)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/mock/process.js)'s implementation of `process.nextTick` does not accept callback arguments. Just override it inside your `main.ts`!

```
process.nextTick = function(callback) {
    const args = [...arguments];

    args.shift();
    setTimeout(() => callback.apply(null, args));
}
```

UPDATE:

It's fixed in v2.2.1: [Commit](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/commit/34d7d752a297c70f73670728e58fc478a5142858)